# Download from the Alfresco to a local folder

Tags: c#, alfresco, dotcmis

I was try download a file from the Alfresco to a local folder with DotCMIS, but the file always save blank, my code:

```
  ISession session = startSession();
  IObjectId id = session.CreateObjectId(fileId);

  Dictionary<String, Object> properties = new Dictionary<String, Object>();

  properties.Add(PropertyIds.Name, file);
  properties.Add(PropertyIds.ObjectId, fileId);
  properties.Add(PropertyIds.ObjectTypeId, "cmis:document,P:cm:titled");


  IDocument docx = session.GetObject(fileId) as IDocument;
  IContentStream content = docx.GetContentStream();
  Stream stream = content.Stream;
  string path = @"C:\Windows\Temp\" + docx.Name;

  using (stream = File.Create(path)) {}
```

Thanks everyone

Comment: Where is the code to write the content stream into your file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked that way:

```
        BufferedStream document = (BufferedStream)content.Stream;

        string path = @"C:\Windows\Temp\" + docx.Name;

        using (FileStream stream = File.Create(path))
        {
            document.CopyTo(stream);
        }
```

Thanks everyone